# How to embed snippet of HTML into a Wordpress page *without* plugins?

Tags: html, wordpress, embed

Searching this topic comes up with custom plugin solutions but I'd prefer to learn what's involved in doing this 'manually'.  The problem:

I have a snippet of HTML which includes a form (an Amazon Payments Donation button) which I'd like to insert into one of my Wordpress pages. When I do it in the Text editor, it quasi works but the resulting code gets seriously modified by Wordpress.

For instance, a `<br></br>` gets added after each hidden input element, and some extraneous `<p></p>` elements get slotted in as well, making the resulting div huge, full of white space (that's impossible to correct via CSS alone).

What would be a non-plugin fix, or is it even possible?

Comment: Why don't you just modify the text of the page? Remove the new lines, etc.?

Comment: The extra br and p elements do not appear in the Text Editor, but I see them when I inspect the page. It seems Wordpress injects them in when serving the page (?)

Comment: Yes it does, by replacing new lines in the editor. Place all of the inputs on a single line and you should be fine.

Comment: Dang, that was it. A bit brutal as the Amazon form has something like 10 lengthy hidden inputs, but it sure works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try cleaning the **p** and **br** tags from the content

simply add this to your functions.php file

```
function clean_shortcodes($content){   
    $array = array (
        '<p>[' => '[', 
        ']</p>' => ']', 
        ']<br />' => ']'
    );
    $content = strtr($content, $array);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'clean_shortcodes');
```

Hope it helps :)